# How to remove a div called with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, dom

Hi everyone i'm searching for a little help.

I have a php page, in this page i have some ajax calls that return a divs...
in one of this div i have a button, if this button will click i have to remove the entire div where button is..

here's my code, not working now :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tutn").live('click',function(e){
   $("#first_time",e).remove() ;
   e.preventDefault() ; 
});});
```

Where id="first_time" is a div called with ajax... and this is my problem .. because the div doen't remove even if i click on the button....
In others world i have to remove the father of the div where button is

this is the html code

```
<div id="first_time">
     <div class="ft_info">
         <input type="button" name="tutn" id="tutn" class="tutbtn" value="no" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For anyone visiting this question. `.live` is deprecated, therefore you must use `.on` instead. As per http://api.jquery.com/live/ - As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're certain the div exists and its ID is `first_time`, just do

```
$('#first_time').remove();
```

The second parameter is supposed to be an existing DOM node, the starting point where jQuery will begin selecting elements. You appear to be passing the `event` object, which isn't what jQuery is expecting.

Furthermore, there is no need to pass a second parameter to an ID selector, as the ID must be unique within the document.

---

A final note on style: Don't put spaces before semi-colons, and don't "save space" by nesting multiple closing `})` pairs. This is gross:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tutn").live('click',function(e){
   $("#first_time",e).remove() ;
   e.preventDefault() ; 
});});
```

There are certain well excepted coding standards that you *must* adopt if you want to be taken seriously:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#tutn").live('click', function (e) {
     $("#first_time",e).remove();
     e.preventDefault(); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't select the div#first_time from the context e.

Just change `$("#first_time",e).remove() ;` to `$("#first_time").remove() ;`

Answer (score 0):

As another option, you can remove the button's "grandparent" with two chained calls to the [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method on `$(this)`, where `this` is the button element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tutn").live('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault() ; 
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});});
```

Comment: yes but even the parent's of the parent :) with your code i remove the first parent. I want to remove id="first_time"

Answer (score 0):

Just one small change should fix it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tutn").live('click',function(e){
       $("#first_time").remove() ;
       e.preventDefault() ; 
    });
});
```

I just removed the `,e` from the remove selector as it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in line 3:

```
$("#first_time").remove() ;
```

The e is wrong there. I wonder that you do not get an js-error.

but i also would recommend to use parent().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tutn").live('click',function(e){
       $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

**You have to use parent() two times to get $('#first_time').**

And I would not use ID's. I would solve the problem with classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the div with id first_time  you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#tutn").live('click', function (e) {
         $("#first_time").remove();
     });
});
```

But if the id is a dynamically changing one then you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#tutn").live('click', function (e) {
             $(this).parent().parent().remove();
         });
});
```